# The implications of not using Async/Await in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asynchronous

I'm building a web app using MVC 5 and I can't use the Async/Await pattern in PartialViewResults because it will cause a runtime error. Because of this I'm not awaiting certain tasks.

For example I have this header UI which is a PartialViewResult that is used on most pages in my APP:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Get UI header for trainee's main details, name, aim, score etc
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="personId"></param>
        /// <param name="aim"></param>
        /// <param name="showScore"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public PartialViewResult _TraineeHeaderDetails(int personId, string aim, bool showScore, bool showEvidenceLink)
        {
            var result = _httpService
                .Get(_urlConfigurations.GetTraineeDetails + personId + "/" + aim);

            if (result.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                //TODO: NG - add proper mvc error page redirect
                throw new Exception("ID not found");
                //RedirectToAction("")

            // use GetAwaiter to get around async/await limitation in MVC 5
            var model = _jsonDeserializer.GetModelAsync<TraineeHeaderViewModel>(result).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            if (model == null) return PartialView(new TraineeHeaderViewModel());

            //For link to trainee summary
            model.PersonId = personId;
            model.AimCode = aim;

            // flag to show/hide graph
            model.ShowScore = showScore;

            // flag to show/hide evidence link
            model.ShowEvidenceLink = showEvidenceLink;

            return PartialView(model);
        }
```

As you can see, my http service call is get where in MVC actions I usually use GetAsync and also when deserializing my JSON result, I'm using .GetAwaiter().GetResult();

My question is, will this affect app performance? Because it's MVC and there is no UI thread that I'm working with (Values being rendered with Razor), I consider what I'm doing to be ok but I am curious to know what others think about this.

Nick

Comment: there are limited worker threads available in the IIS Application pool to server requests, using async await would release the request thread until the async operation completes

Answer (score 0):

> As you can see, my http service call is get where in MVC actions I usually use GetAsync and also when deserializing my JSON result, I'm using .GetAwaiter().GetResult();

Personally, I prefer to use synchronous APIs when I need to call them synchronously, as opposed to blocking (`GetAwaiter().GetResult()`). The blocking approach assumes that the asynchronous method you're calling uses `ConfigureAwait(false)` for every `await`. If they forgot one, then you've got a potential deadlock.

> My question is, will this affect app performance?

It probably won't affect performance in the sense of time-to-first-byte. It will definitely impact your scalability; if your web server is hit hard or has a sudden inrush of requests, it won't be able to scale as well as it could using a pure-`async` solution.

But there isn't anything you can do about it. It's a limitation of ASP.NET classic (fixed in ASP.NET Core). That's life.